# Force stop Azure App Config use spring active profiles as label

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-app-configuration

I have a working spring boot application that loads properties from Azure AppConfig service

Here is a bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      appconfiguration:
        stores[0]:
          feature-flags:
            enabled: true
          selects[0]:
            key-filter: ${key-filter}
          connection-string: ${connection-string}
```

It's all working just fine
BUT
If any spring profile is active, Azure AppConfig uses it as a label filter, it's event says in their doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config-readme?view=azure-java-stable

And also the profile being added to the BootstrapPropertySource
you could find in logs when you run the app:

without profile: BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-${key-filter}/${your_link}/ '}

with profile: BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-${key-filter}/${your_link}/profile'}

and in case with profile enabled, properties are not being loaded
I tried option with adding 'label-filter: ,' but it does not work

Maybe there is any way to force AppConfig NOT use the spring profile at all?

Answer (score 0):

You you set the label filter but don't give it a value it will load all configuration settings without a label. For more info see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/app-configuration-support?tabs=azure-ad#selecting-configurations